# Telephone API does nothing

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I made a simple telephone app for android, I was do Permission internet in Android Manifest file on android studio, I use this method for make my app can be used for calling `android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE`.

but when I run my code nothing happens

this is the first class :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val mobno: String = "1234567890"
    val REQUEST_PHONE_CALL = 1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val call = findViewById<Button>(R.id.phone_call)

        call.setOnClickListener {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {

            }
        }
    }

    private fun makecall() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.fromParts("tel", mobno, null))
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PHONE_CALL) {
            makecall()
        }
    }
}
```

this is my main_activity.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/phone_call"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:text="Place Call" />
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.telephoneappkotlin">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

in my graddle I don't use any Library implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: in MainActivity class I added android.permission.CALL_PHONE, why I must add again the permisison

Comment: You need to add it in the manifest. and use Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE instead of android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE in your MainActivity

Comment: I was ready to add you permission but, its same thing doesn't work.